# How can I set a property on a Controller, or Global Variable, from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a checkbox in the NavBar element of my ASP MVC 5 site.  The state of that checkbox is used on each page to determine if the Grid will show Inactive records in addition to active records.

I have a static class with a static prop that I am trying to write to from the _Layout.cshtml with some jQuery so that each of my controllers can check that same prop on there Index() method.

I tried the below but then I realized that it wouldn't work as one is Client and the other Server.

So, is there a way to do this or something similar?

**_Layout.cshtml (html)**

```
<div class="nav pull-right checkbox navbar-btn">
                @Html.CheckBox("ShowInactive", false) Show Inactive
</div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml (JS, very bottom)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ShowInactive").prop("checked", @HttpContext.Current.Application["ShowInactive"]);
        $("#ShowInactive").click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                @HttpContext.Current.Application["ShowInactive"] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                @HttpContext.Current.Application["ShowInactive"] = false;
            }
            //This is to make the grid reload after the checkbox is changed.
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**GlobalVariables.cs**

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static bool ShowInactive
    {
        get { return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Application["ShowInactive"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application["ShowInactive"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing server side code with client side code, your script won't work as you are trying to change a server side value inside client code. What i would do is to set a ShowInactive value on a cookie (if you want to persist it), then in the server side read it, then your client code just needs to update the cookie value and reload the page.

Comment: @Alberto Yes, I realize that I'm mixing the two and that's why it didn't work.  I just don't know what to do different.  I'll look into the cookie idea, thanks.

Comment: You need a way to persist a change from client side and read it server side, you could use a cookie, an httpheader, query string, it depends on your needs, if you need to persist user selection i would go for the cookie, Then in server side you just need to change your getter for ShowInactive, and then in client side when page loads try to read the cookie  and set the checkbox value and when the users clicks it change the cookie value and reload.

Comment: I currently do not need to persist beyond that user's session but that doesn't mean I won't eventually.  It is a WEIRD requirement after all. I will see what I can do with the cookie idea.  Hadn't even occurred to me, I'm always showing my Desktop roots I guess...

Comment: Good luck i'm sure you will do it!!

Answer (score -1):

Use this :

```
document.getElementById('ShowInactive').checked = true;
```

OR

```
$('#ShowInactive').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

OR

```
$("#ShowInactive").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused.  I can set and get the value of the checkbox from Javascript just fine with `.prop` and `this.checked` like I have shown.  My problem is setting a value from a static class file.  Like a Global Variable or on a Controller.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

$("#ShowInactive").prop("checked", true);
});

Comment: I'm not following on how this let's me set a value in a server side static class ? Like a controller property even.  The code I have shown already get's and sets the checkbox's value.  Sorry if my question is unclear.